# How to send "waiting" to user while bot is processing operation?

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am migrating a bot from V3 to V4 and I need to send to user messages about processing status.

When user send "hello bot, what's amount of the sales on january 2019?"

While bot is processing and do not send response about this question to frontend project, I want to send 3 events from frontend project to bot with values bellow:

- First event will sent after 7 seconds: the name will be "waiting" and value will be 7;
- Second event will sent after 15 seconds: the name will be "wating" and value will be 15;
- Third event will be sent after 20 seconds: the name will be "wating" and value will be "20";

The bot will response those events as the code bellow:

```
if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event)
{
   if (activity.Name == "waiting")
   {
      var entity = new Entity();
      entity.SetAs(new Mention()
      {
            Text = "waiting",
      });
      if (activity.Value.ToString() == "7")
      {
         var replyMessage = activity.CreateReply();
         replyMessage.Entities.Add(entity);
         await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(Helper.MessageToUser.WaitAMinute);
      }
      else if (activity.Value.ToString() == "15")
      {
         var replyMessage = activity.CreateReply();
         replyMessage.Entities.Add(entity);                        
         await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(Helper.MessageToUser.IAmHere);
      }
      else if (activity.Value.ToString() == "20")
      {
         var replyMessage = activity.CreateReply();
         await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(Helper.MessageToUser.IGotIt);
      }
   }
}
```

Is it a good idea?

Comment: These conditions are a little unclear. Do you want each of those messages to be sent after a specific amount of time? "More than 3 seconds and less than 6 seconds" is not a specific time. If the process delays for more than six seconds do you want the bot to have sent all three messages or do you just want to send the last one?

Comment: Also, have you considered sending a typing activity?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117147/set-time-of-activity-typing-animation

Comment: Hello @KyleDelaney!! "Do you want each of those messages to be sent after a specific amount of time?". Yes, I do! "If the process delays for more than six seconds do you want the bot to have sent all three messages or do you just want to send the last one?". I want to send the last one.

Comment: @KyleDelaney "have you considered sending a typing activity?". May be, but I would like to send a little text too.

Comment: I feel like this indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of how time works. If the bot doesn't know ahead of time how long the task is going to take, how could it possibly know to not send messages 1 and 2 before it sends message 3? You said "While bot is processing a operation" but did you perhaps mean to say that you want to send the message after the operation has finished processing?

Comment: Hello @KyleDelaney. I guess frontend project can have a counter and while frontend project waits to return from bot about a messagemsent by user, the frontend project can send events to bot time to time. In this case, the event has the number of seconds passed in the counter. Is ti a good Idea?

Comment: That doesn't address my questions. Please rewrite your question to explain what you actually want to happen. Show three example conversations including all the messages from the bot and the user, and how much time has passed between each message.

Comment: OK @KyleDelaney. I will rewrite. Sorry for that!

Comment: @KyleDelaney, the question was edited.

Comment: Thank you, your question is clearer now. But it seems to be that there's no need for your front-end application to send activities to the bot as it waits (you are using Direct Line, right?) Why not just have the long-running process keep track of time and send proactive messages to the bot that way? And if this is a bot that you're migrating from v3 to v4, can you edit your question to include how you did this in v3?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney, yes. I am resting these days. I will edit my question on tuesday.

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: Hello @KyleDelaney. This task is stopped in my job. We will review this topic coming soon.